# Comentários facebook X wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook

Como fazer para que os comentários feitos em uma fan page do Facebook sejam também publicados automaticamente no site? Algumas fan pages, como a do Terra, por exemplo, mostram a seguinte mensagem abaixo dos comentários: "Esse comentário também será publicado em www.terra.com.br"

Meu site é wordpress

Aqui o que eu quero, em vermelho: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaFSu.jpg

Comment: Hugo, se você achou a solução, poste como resposta abaixo e marque-a como aceita. Utilizar o campo acima de pergunta para isso deixa seu post confuso. Este site não é como fóruns, visite o [tour] para ver como funciona.

Comment: @Articuno ok, obrigado pela dica amigo, já coloquei a resposta, mas só consigo clicar como solução amanhã (quando eu clico em 'aceitar resposta' ele diz que só posso fazer isso amanhã) .

Answer (score 1):

OK pessoal... consegui resolver aqui depois de muita luta, o fluxo é o seguinte:

1- crie seu facebook app com qualquer nome; 2- configure o mesmo para ser um app de um site e torne o mesmo público; 3- na configuração de plataforma do app, selecione 'site'; 4- insira a tag

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="(seu app id)">
```

antes do fechamento do head; 5- insira o jdk logo após a abertura do :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=(seu app id)";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

6- Insira a tag no local que você quer que apareça a caixa de comentários:

7- vá na configuração de moderação de comentários, clique em configurações e ative 'espelhamento de comentários' ou 'comments mirroring' ,algo assim. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

Nesse momento os comentários já devem estar aparecendo com 'espelhamento'.

Qualquer dúvida podem me perguntar. abraço.